# How to delete row in lwc datatable and corresponding object

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, datatable

I have a datable with PermissionSetAssignment objects and I need to delete the record selected from user but when I click delete nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from "lwc";
import getUsersAndPermissionSets from "@salesforce/apex/PermissionSetsController.getUsersAndPermissionSets";
import removePermSet from "@salesforce/apex/RemoveUserFromPermSet.removePermSet";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";

const actions = [
  { label: "Remove", name: "remove" }
];

const columns = [
  { label: "Role Name", fieldName: "Role", type: "text" },
  { label: "Assignee Name", fieldName: "Assignee", type: "text" },
  {
    type: 'action',
    typeAttributes: {rowActions : actions}
  },
];

export default class usersTable extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  @track showAssignees = "Show Assignees";
  @track isVisible = false;
  @track data = [];
  @track columns = columns;
  @api recordId;

  handleClick(event) {
    const label = event.target.label;

    if (label === "Show Assignees") {
      this.showAssignees = "Hide Assignees";
      this.isVisible = true;
    } else if (label === "Hide Assignees") {
      this.showAssignees = "Show Assignees";
      this.isVisible = false;
    }
  }

  @wire(getUsersAndPermissionSets)
  users({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      let currentData = [];

      data.forEach((row) => {
        let rowData = {};

        rowData.Name = row.Name;
        rowData.CreatedDate = row.CreatedDate;

        // PermissionSet related data
        if (row.PermissionSet) {
          rowData.Role = row.PermissionSet.Name;
        }

        // Assignee releated data
        if (row.Assignee) {
          rowData.Assignee = row.Assignee.Name;
        }

        currentData.push(rowData);
      });

      this.data = currentData;
    } else if (error) {
      window.console.log(error);
    }
  }

  handleRowActon(event) {
    const row = event.detail.row;

    removePermSet(row.Id).then((result) => {
      this.data = result;
      console.log(result);
    });
    this.showSuccessToast();
    window.location.reload();
  }

  showSuccessToast() {
    const event = new ShowToastEvent({
      label: "Record updated",
      message: "User successfully removed",
      variant: "success"
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

Apex class:

```
public class RemoveUserFromPermSet {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Boolean removePermSet(Id lwcRowId){
        PermissionSetAssignment selectedPermSetAss = [SELECT Id, PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name, 
                                    AssigneeId, Assignee.Name 
                                    FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE Id = :lwcRowId];

        
        try{
            delete selectedPermSetAss;
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: first add catch block for `removePermSet` action in lwc, so you 'll know apex method processed successfully or not, then only 'll know what is the root cause issue.

Comment: @sdandamud1 Won't work, catching the error in Apex.

Comment: @sfdcfox agreed , catching errors needs both places , lwc & Apex as well

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if the result was successful or not, which it isn't, because (a) you're not setting the parameters correctly; you must pass in an object in the form of `{paramName: paramValue,...}`, and (b) `cacheable=true` methods **cannot** perform any DML operation.

Just delete the record and let the client handle it:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
public static void removePermSet(Id lwcRowId){
    delete [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE Id = :lwcRowId];
}
```

We can avoid reloading the page by storing the response for a later call to refreshApex:

```
  usersAndPermissionSetsResponse;
  @wire(getUsersAndPermissionSets)
  users(response) {
    const { error, data } = response;
    this.usersAndPermissionSetsResponse = response;
    if (data) {
      this.data = data.map((row) => ({
        ...row,
        Role: row.PermissionSet?.Name,
        Assignee: row.Assignee?.Name,
      }));
    }
  }
```

And then rewrite handleRowAction to catch the error, and refresh on success:

```
  async handleRowActon(event) {
    const row = event.detail.row;
    try {
        await removePermSet({lwcRowId:row.Id});
        this.showSuccessToast();
        refreshApex(this.usersAndPermissionSetsResponse);
    } catch(e) {
        // handle error here.
    }
  }
```

You'll need to:

```
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
```

Comment: Thanks, very usefull